# Which text is more effective to encourage users to leave review for Android App

Tags: mobile, android, feedback

I have prepared 2 types of text which used to ask user to leave review in Google Play store for Android app.

It is a dialog, which will pop up, if user has used this app for N times for last M days.

### First Text

> Hello!
>
> My name is xxx. I'm the solo developer who develops JStock
>   Android. JStock Android development is difficult and slow. It takes
>   months to build, test and deploy a polished feature. If you like to
>   support my work, please leave me a nice review in the market. Thank
>   you for giving me the extra push to keep moving forward.

### Second Text

> We love you!
>
> Can we assume that the feeling's mutual? If you've been enjoying our
>   app, we'd really appreciate it if you could leave us a nice review in
>   the market. It'll really help us grow :)

I was wondering, which type of text will yield a better "conversion" result?

Comment: I think that's going to depend on your users. You should be aware, however, that there's a small segment of the population (I'm one) who bursts into unreasoning, flaming, hatred at a pop-up that interrupts my attempt to get something done. When I'm hit with such a pop up, the question isn't 'will I leave good feedback?', it's 'Will I leave a nasty note with my one star rating or not?'. I can't stand apps that interrupt me to try to get feedback.

Comment: I prefer the first one. It seems more genuine and less marketing-y, but I work in marketing so take it for what it's worth. EDIT-- I'd say if your app is a more "iphoney" audience, #2 may be better, but if your app is more technical, #1 will be vastly superior.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelKohne. Don't pop up the dialog. You will always interrupt the flow of the user, and they will always hate you for it. If this leads to more reviews, they'll be bad ones. You have to be more subtle about it. Find the point in your app's flow when the user feels good. When there's a break in their planning. Ie. choose a moment when they've finished something and feel positive. Then you can show a message. You still shouldn't pop it up, though. You could, for instance, find a nice neutral space in the home screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The second text** is clearly the *winner* here.

Its more human. Its clear, non technical and it has a positive approach to it (in comparison to the first).

No offense but most users don't care if it took you months or years or how hard the process of building the app is... they want to use it and enjoy it enough to reuse it and tell people why they should try it or why they recommend it.

Comment: Seeing how that comment was made in '14, I think the situation changed a little. Every other app is using the "hey give us some good review plz :)" nowadays, so having a more personal message that shows the passion of one person behind it can connect to more people. But I still agree that OP's first text is way too technical and unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 1):

I like the first one better,
sine it gives the user a bit of the hard work, blood, sweat and tears you had to go to in order to make this app happen.
The second text option is a bit too sweat and flattering to my taste.
Also, the 1st text ends up in motivating people to give you an extra push, like your'e saying: I need this to go on another day. It's (not for) you. It's (for) me.

Best of luck anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I like them both, one comes off as more professional and the other more fun and loose. The issue with getting reviews is that when someone reads that **First Text** they might not take the time to read the whole thing and just hit the "close" button before you can make your point. For that reason I definitely lean more towards the **Second Text**. So when it comes down to it I think the second text will be more effective in the long run as it is more clear cut and gets to the point in a fun way at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

So, the three answers above are "a", "b" and "a & b".

That pretty much covers it :-)

The real answer is an empirical test: Insert messages a and b at random and see which generates clicks on the feedback button.

There might also see what's called a mixture distribution: message 1 is good for one population, and message 2 for another subset. This can be detected statistically from the A/B trial using mixture models of the response data. I think that's likely over-kill here.

PS: I think someone could write an app service to implement this properly: That might actually be a nice service: Data could be aggregated over many apps to craft a maximally effective message, plus you could also emulate the play-store rating system to capture not only intent to rate, but also the ratings.